# How to get return value from a forked / spawned process in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, output, fork, spawn

My simple test program:

```
pid = Process.spawn("sleep 10;date")
```

How can I place the output (eg stdout) of the "date" command in a variable when it is available? I don't want to use a file for the data exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [whole bunch of ways](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) to run commands from Ruby. The simplest for your case is to use [backticks](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60), which capture output:

```
`sleep 10; date`
# "Tue Jun 23 10:15:39 EDT 2015\n"
```

If you want something more similar to `Process.spawn`, use the [open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) stdlib:

```
require 'open3'

stdin, stdout, wait_thr = Open3.popen2("sleep 10; date")

stdin.close
Process.wait(wait_thr.pid)
stdout.read
# "Tue Jun 23 10:15:39 EDT 2015\n"
stdout.close
```